# Find volume of the solid in SPHERICAL COORS

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4z$ and above the cone $z = \sqrt{3x^2 + 3y^2}$

I know that the upper bound of p is $4cos \phi$ but I'm having trouble finding the lower bound.

Answer (score 2):

Converting to cylindrical then spherical coordinates, we have:
$$
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4z \iff r^2 + z^2 = 4z \iff \rho^2 = 4\rho\cos\phi \iff \rho = 4\cos\phi \\
z = \sqrt{3x^2 + 3y^2} \iff z = \sqrt 3 r \iff \rho\cos\phi = \sqrt 3 \rho\sin\phi \iff \tan\phi = \frac{1}{\sqrt 3} \iff \phi = \frac{\pi}{6}
$$

It's clear that $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$. Slicing the region at some fixed angle $\theta$, we obtain a slice in the $zr$-half-plane whose cross-section is bounded by the vertical line $r = 0$, the circle $r^2 + (z - 2)^2 = 4 \iff \rho = 4\cos\phi$, and the diagonal line $z = \sqrt 3 r \iff \phi = \frac{\pi}{6}$. Thus, we obtain:
$$
V = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/6} \int_0^{4\cos\phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi \, d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta 
$$